# Left motorcycle lights on all night; won't turn on

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

I got a 2017 Yamaha FZ07. I accidentally left the key on came back to my bike the next day and it’s completely dead tried to jump start got nothing tried push starting it started but when i slowed down the bike shut off any idea on what it might be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and recharge the battery on a low amperage (2A) for a while until it gets back up to voltage (~13vdc). Once it gets back to voltage, I doubt you'll have any issues with it. I'd suspect the reason it wouldn't run long was the fact the battery didn't have any juice in it. I'm surprised it started at all, really. An overnight recharge should leave it in pretty good shape, I'd think. I doubt you've done much damage to it, but when you completely drain it, there's always some amount which will occur.